# Rewriting a Google sheet calculation to SQL format, but experiencing a 'Loop' problem

Tags: sql

I am trying to convert a sheet calculation to build a similar table in SQL.
We have multiple order records stored in a table, and the target dates can change multiple times throughout the lifetime of the order.

Ideal table format example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q2jypEV6bPynOTlMuwfjDjykzl4iPsjoJ3G2R2Uqd3w/edit#gid=0

Example SQL Server Script:

```
WITH record_history AS (

    SELECT
        'FALSE' AS change,
        NULL AS old_date,
        NULL AS adjustment_value,
        CAST('1/1/2023' AS DATE) AS recommended_date
  
    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        'TRUE' AS change,
        CAST('1/1/2023' AS DATE) AS old_date,
        9 AS adjustment_value,
        CAST('1/5/2023' AS DATE) AS recommended_date

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        'TRUE' AS change,
        CAST('1/10/2023' AS DATE) AS old_date,
        9 AS adjustment_value,
        CAST('1/20/2023' AS DATE) AS recommended_date

    UNION ALL
  
    SELECT
        'TRUE' AS change,
        CAST('1/20/2023' AS DATE) AS old_date,
        9 AS adjustment_value,
        CAST('1/30/2023' AS DATE) AS recommended_date
),
create_adjusted_date AS (

    SELECT
        change,
        old_date,
        adjustment_value,
        recommended_date,
        DATEADD(DAY, adjustment_value, old_date) AS adjusted_date
    FROM
        record_history
)

    SELECT 
        change,
        old_date,
        adjustment_value,
        adjusted_date,
        recommended_date,
        adjusted_date,
        GREATEST(recommended_date, adjusted_date) AS new_date
    FROM
        create_adjusted_date
```

The issue is: the **old date** for any records identifying multiple changes in the table should reflect the **new date** from the prior record.

How would this be written in SQL if the field calculations are written once but constantly rely on another? (old_date, adjusted_date, and new_date being the dynamic fields)

EDIT: Simplified the request for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use recursive common table expressions (CTEs) to handle the circular dependency.

> Simply put, Common Table Expressions (also known as WITH clauses) are
> essentially named subqueries. They also provide additional features
> like recursion. If you're new to subqueries, I recommend you read the
> SQL Subqueries article before continuing.

https://learnsql.com/blog/improving-query-readability-common-table-expressions

Here's an updated version using recursive CTEs:

**Update based on question change.**
The recursive part of the CTE joins the record_history table with the previous iteration of recursive_cte using the new_date and old_date fields. This ensures that the old date references the new date from the previous row. The recursive part also calculates the adjusted_date and new_date fields based on the adjustment value. From there, the outer query then selects the fields from the recursive_cte CTE.

```
WITH record_history AS (
    SELECT
        'FALSE' AS change,
        NULL AS old_date,
        NULL AS adjustment_value,
        CAST('2023-01-01' AS DATE) AS recommended_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'TRUE' AS change,
        CAST('2023-01-01' AS DATE) AS old_date,
        9 AS adjustment_value,
        CAST('2023-01-05' AS DATE) AS recommended_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'TRUE' AS change,
        CAST('2023-01-10' AS DATE) AS old_date,
        9 AS adjustment_value,
        CAST('2023-01-20' AS DATE) AS recommended_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'TRUE' AS change,
        CAST('2023-01-20' AS DATE) AS old_date,
        9 AS adjustment_value,
        CAST('2023-01-30' AS DATE) AS recommended_date
),
recursive_cte AS (
    SELECT
        change,
        old_date,
        adjustment_value,
        recommended_date,
        DATEADD(DAY, adjustment_value, old_date) AS adjusted_date,
        recommended_date AS new_date
    FROM
        record_history
    WHERE
        change = 'FALSE'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        rh.change,
        cad.new_date AS old_date,
        rh.adjustment_value,
        rh.recommended_date,
        DATEADD(DAY, rh.adjustment_value, cad.new_date) AS adjusted_date,
        GREATEST(rh.recommended_date, DATEADD(DAY, rh.adjustment_value, cad.new_date)) AS new_date
    FROM
        record_history rh
    INNER JOIN
        recursive_cte cad ON cad.new_date = rh.old_date
    WHERE
        rh.change = 'TRUE'
)
SELECT
    change,
    old_date,
    adjustment_value,
    adjusted_date,
    recommended_date,
    new_date
FROM
    recursive_cte
```

Comment: Hi James, thank you for your answer. I edited and simplified the problem and spreadsheet. 

If I were to use a recursive CTE, would that allow the "old date" to be reference new date from the previous row? It currently flows as old_date -> adjusted_date -> new_date -> old_date, etc.

How would you rewrite the newly provided syntax to do so?

Comment: Yes, you can use a recursive CTE so that the old date references the new date from the previous row. The CTE allows you to repeatedly reference the result of the previous iteration.  I'll post an update to my code, based on your update.

Comment: Would recursive CTEs still be reliable when working with larger data sets? (600k+ rows)
In addition to this, the possibility of additional columns which are calculated similarly to new date?

Comment: The performance and reliability of recursive CTEs can vary depending on the database system, the complexity of the recursive logic, and the size of the data set. Always try to optimize the query as much as possible, but there are also alternatives to CTE you could try, such as using nested sets or materialized path models, that may give better performance and scalability for large data sets.

Comment: It seems that even when working with materialized data sets, it was still giving issues due to infinite recursion unfortunately.

Do you happen to know if we're able to achieve a similar result using WHILE or other loop like functions?

Comment: If you're using a DBMS that supports it, like PL/SQL (Oracle) or T-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server), then WHILE loops would be an option. I don't know enough about those systems to say whether or not there would be a performance gain.